# Working with nested maps inside a JSON payload

Tags: json, flutter, dart, maps

I am still learning how to work with JSON. I have a new JSON payload returned from an API. The payload is made up of a list of maps and inside the maps are nested maps.

In the Maps returned, I have an element that is another map but it has no elements. How do I handle this?

The element #6, **features**, has no items:

```
Map (10 items)
0:"addressLine1" -> "3223B Palm Desert Ln"
1:"city" -> "Missouri City"
2:"state" -> "TX"
3:"zipCode" -> "77459"
4:"formattedAddress" -> "3223B Palm Desert Ln, Missouri City, TX 77459"
5:"county" -> "Fort Bend"
6:"features" -> Map (0 items)
7:"id" -> "3223B-Palm-Desert-Ln,-Missouri-City,-TX-77459"
8:"longitude" -> -95.554532
9:"latitude" -> 29.581225
```

I have tried something similar to the way a Map is handled in the next item below which is taxAssessment but I get an error:
**The argument type 'Map<String?, Features>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Features?'**

```
factory PropertyInformation.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return PropertyInformation(
      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      formattedAddress: json['formattedAddress'],
      assessorId: json['assessorId'],
      bedrooms: json['bedrooms'],
      county: json['county'],
      legalDescription: json['legalDescription'],
      squareFootage: json['squareFootage'],
      subdivision: json['subdivision'],
      yearBuilt: json['yearBuilt'],
      bathrooms: json['bathrooms'],
      lotSize: json['lotSize'],
      propertyType: json['propertyType'],
      lastSaleDate: json['lastSaleDate'] == null ? DateTime.now() : DateTime.parse(json['lastSaleDate']),
      //features: Features.fromJson(json['features']),
      features: Map.from(json['features']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, Features>(
              k, Features.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      taxAssessment: Map.from(json['taxAssessment']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, TaxAssessment>(
              k, TaxAssessment.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      propertyTaxes: Map.from(json['propertyTaxes']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, PropertyTax>(
              k, PropertyTax.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      owner: Owner.fromJson(json['owner']),
      id: json['id'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
    );
  }
```

This is the Features class:

```
class Features {
  String? architectureType;
  bool? cooling;
  String? coolingType;
  String? exteriorType;
  int? floorCount;
  String? foundationType;
  bool? garage;
  String? garageType;
  bool? heating;
  String? heatingType;
  bool? pool;
  String? roofType;
  int? roomCount;
  int? unitCount;

  Features({
    required this.architectureType,
    required this.cooling,
    required this.coolingType,
    required this.exteriorType,
    required this.floorCount,
    required this.foundationType,
    required this.garage,
    required this.garageType,
    required this.heating,
    required this.heatingType,
    required this.pool,
    required this.roofType,
    required this.roomCount,
    required this.unitCount,
  });

  factory Features.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return Features(
      architectureType: json['architectureType'],
      cooling: json['cooling'],
      coolingType: json['coolingType'],
      exteriorType: json['exteriorType'],
      floorCount: json['floorCount'],
      foundationType: json['foundationType'],
      garage: json['garage'],
      garageType: json['garageType'],
      heating: json['heating'],
      heatingType: json['heatingType'],
      pool: json['pool'],
      roofType: json['roofType'],
      roomCount: json['roomCount'],
      unitCount: json['unitCount'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'architectureType': architectureType,
      'cooling': cooling,
      'coolingType': coolingType,
      'exteriorType': exteriorType,
      'floorCount': floorCount,
      'foundationType': foundationType,
      'garage': garage,
      'garageType': garageType,
      'heating': heating,
      'heatingType': heatingType,
      'pool': pool,
      'roofType': roofType,
      'roomCount': roomCount,
      'unitCount': unitCount,
    };
  }
```

How do I handle an empty Map object?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if features are only an object, you'll like this `Feature.fromJson(json['features'])`. If the feature is a features list, you'll `json['features'].map((json)=>Features.fromJson(json)).toList()`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made the change you suggested and evaluated it in the debug console and got this error:   json['features'].map((json)=>Features.fromJson(json)).toList()
Unhandled exception:
type '(dynamic) => Features' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'
#0      PropertyInformation.Eval ()
#1      new PropertyInformation.fromJson (package:for_testing/models/property_information_model.dart:76:21)
#2      _DataScreenState.getItems (package:for_testing/screens/data_screen.dart:53:48)
<asynchronous suspension>

Comment: The calling function returns this error:  _TypeError (type '(dynamic) => Features' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform')

Comment: then it is necessary to see the returned data

Comment: The execution stops at this line while processing the JSON:  6:"features" -> Map (0 items). I think it throws an error because the map has 0 items and I am not handling it in the correct way.